# Passing data to modal and binding it to a reactive form

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I am using angular 4.3.5 and ngx-bootstrap 1.9.0.

I have a modal that has a reactive form with a few inputs and I want to use the same modal for both entering data and editing data. The problem I'm facing is that I can't access the object passed to the modal in any of the lifecycle hooks (it is undefined) and because of that I can't bind the data to the form.

This is how I pass the object:

```
this.modal = this.modalService.show(MyModalComponent);
this.modal.content.user = this.model.users.find(x => x.id === id);
```

and everything I tried in the modal end didn't work so far. Any ideas on how to make this work?